# Mobile version of Outlook.com not working properly on my Android

Tags: mobile, outlook.com

How do I view my new Outlook.com version of Hotmail as a mobile version as I used to before? The Outlook.com version does not work properly on my Android mobile phone.

Comment: Have you considered adding it as an account in your Android's mail app, instead of trying to view it online?

Comment: Or, possibly, using the [Outlook.com Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.outlook.Z7)?

Answer (score 2):

The official URL to be able to access a mobile friendly version of Outlook.com is http://m.mail.live.com/.

[More details about all mobile friendly access options provided here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/outlook-to-go).

Comment: I wonder why they wouldn't auto-redirect based on the user agent.

Comment: http://m.mail.live.com/ opens a sign-in page on the desktop browser that is different than the normal page i.e. it doesn't have an image on the left of the login form that . It however opened up the full version after logging in. So there currently doesn't seem to be a mobile friendly version of Outlook.com similar to Google's m.gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

I was able to see the "mobile site" link on the bottom after I deleted all my cookies and browsing history.